# How can I use LVM snapshots in Ubuntu?

Tags: lvm

I've installed Ubuntu using these options:

- Erase the disk and install Ubuntu
- Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation
- Use LVM

How can I create LVM snapshots, so that I'm able to revert system changes when it's necessary?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Note: all commands should be done from `sudo`*

#### First, reduce size of your root volume to make some room for a snapshot volume

- Boot from Live CD
- `fdisk -l` to see name of your device.

  ```
  Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
  /dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
  /dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
  /dev/sda3  2050048 500117503 498067456 237.5G Linux filesystem
  ```

  `/dev/sda3` in my case
- `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 crypt1` to decrypt your volume
- `vgscan --mknodes` to find all volume groups

  ```
  Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  ```
- `vgchange -ay` to activate all your volume groups

  ```
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
  ```
- `lvreduce -r -L -20G /dev/ubuntu-vg/root` to reduce size of your root volume by 20 Gb. This may take a while (it took ~4 min for me).
  That space will later be used to create LVM snapshots.
- `vgs` to see that you actually got 20G of free space

  ```
  VG           #PV   #LV   #SN   Attr     VSize     VFree
  ubuntu-vg     1      2     0   wz--n-   230.44g   20.01g
  ```
- `reboot` and remove Live CD

#### Create a snapshot (i.e., activate "experimentation" mode)

Now whenever you want to do something risky with your system, run the following command

- `lvcreate -s -n snap -L 20G /dev/ubuntu-vg/root`
  Note: `/dev/ubuntu-vg/root` is a logical volume that you want to have a snapshot of
- `lvs` to see that the volume has been created

  ```
  LV     VG            Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg     owi-aos--- 201.59g                                                    
  snap   ubuntu-vg     swi-a-s---  20.00g      root   0.00                                   
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg     -wi-ao----  15.90g
  ```

  The snapshot is active from the moment you run `lvcreate`. You can now start experimenting with new things.

#### Scenario #1: You want to revert changes

- `lvconvert --merge /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-snap`

  ```
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/root contains a filesystem in use.
  Can't merge over open origin volume.
  Merging of snapshot ubuntu-vg/snap will occur on next activation of ubuntu-vg/root.
  ```
- `reboot`

#### Scenario #2: You want to persist changes

- `lvremove /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-snap`

#### In Conclusion

You basically have to run `lvcreate` to start the process and then either run `lvconvert --merge` or `lvremove` to end it.

Keep in mind that when the snapshot is active, due to Copy-On-Write strategy all the changes are saved to those 20Gb of space (or whatever value you set).
One way of checking the remaining capacity is to look at Data% column of `lvs` command.

Comment: Don't you need to shrink the filesystem before you run `lvreduce` on its container?

Comment: @Mark `-r` flag does that

Comment: Is it safe to run `lvconvert --merge` when filesystem is mounted, or do you need to do it from LiveCD?

Comment: @CharlesB yes, you should run it when it's mounted

Comment: Hi, I have a stupid question. When I try to `lvremove /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-snap` I get `Logical volume ubuntu-vg/snap in use`. I want to persist changes after finally succedding in updating. And btw. Great answer.